# The Derivative of $\cos(x-2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would think that the solution would be $-\sin(x-2)$, but when i use WolframAlpha it says that the answer is $\sin(2-x)$. Are these $2$ answers equivalent or I am missing some fact here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SHOW YOUR WORK. or we don't know where you went wrong.

Comment: @ahn: Can you provide a link to the WA page? When I tried it, it matches what you arrived at.

Comment: It's pretty clearly *not* $\sin(2-x)$. @DonLarynx, I don't think miscopying from WA is the sort of work that can be shown.

Comment: Your calculation is correct, and Wolfram Mathematica agrees (obviously).

Comment: Woops, totally meant cos(x-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function, $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

In particular, $\frac{d}{dx}[\cos(x-2)]=-\sin(x-2)=\sin(2-x)$.

Likewise, $\cos(x)$ is an even function, so $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: I see it now, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule,

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \cos(x - 2) \right) = -\sin(x - 2) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(x - 2\right) = -\sin(x - 2)
$$

Since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function, $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$ so $-\sin(x - 2) = \sin(2 - x)$